# Test connection between devices on a network

Tags: testing, networking, connection, break

Is it possible to test connections between devices on a network? How can you find out where the break in the connection is? Example of a network

cloud server <-----> modem <----> router <-----> master radio <---> slave radio <----> on site fixed field device

Thank you